"Reflex field" for $\mathbb H/\Gamma$ for $\Gamma$ non-congruence
Suppose $\Gamma$ is a non-congruence arithmetic subgroup of $PGL_2(\mathbb Z)$, and $\mathbb H$ is the upper half plane of $\mathbb C$. Then by Belyi's theorem we know $\mathbb H/\Gamma$ is an algebraic curve defined over a number field, and this field grows while shrinking $\Gamma$.
For the congruence case, theory of Shimura variety ensures all $\mathrm {Sh}_K$ (for $K\subset PGL_2(\mathbb A_f)$ open compact) are defined over $\mathbb Q$, and the philosophy is gluing several galois-conjugates of a curve defined over a big field to make it defined over $\mathbb Q$, and the method is "canonical": for neat $K'\subset K$ a finite index subgroup, the canonical map $\mathrm{Sh_{K'}}\to \mathrm{Sh}_{K}$ is finite etale and descends to $\mathbb Q$, and when $K'$ is normal, the Galois group for this cover is $K/K'$.
My question is: Can we do the same for $\mathbb H/\Gamma$ when $\Gamma$ is not congruence? Which means, canonically associate an algebraic curve $C(\Gamma)$ over $\mathbb Q$ for each $\Gamma$, satisfying (assuming $\Gamma$ torsion free): for a finite index subgroup $\Gamma'\subset \Gamma$, the map $C(\Gamma')\to C(\Gamma)$ is finite etale and defined over $\mathbb Q$, and when $\Gamma'$ is normal, the Galois group for this cover "like" $\Gamma/\Gamma'$.
Any reference will be appreciated.

The technique of taking a disjoint union of Galois conjugates works for any algebraic variety defined over a finite separable extension of a field.  Are you asking whether the Galois conjugates of $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ are also of the form $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma'$ for an arithmetic subgroup $\Gamma'$ of $\textbf{PGL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

@JasonStarr I have finally figured out what I want to ask...  Please see the modified version of the post.

Please, do not use the word "congruent" in this context, as it means something else.

@MoisheKohan okok

The theory of Shimura varieties doesn't do what you claim it does, I'm afraid. If $\Gamma$ is a congruence subgroup of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ of level $N$, then you always get a canonical model of $\Gamma \backslash \mathcal{H}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$, but it will not necessarily descend all the way to $\mathbb{Q}$. Even if it does descend, it will not descend "canonically", so you cannot expect this to be compatible with the action of $\Gamma / \Gamma'$ on $C(\Gamma')$ for $\Gamma' \trianglelefteq \Gamma$.

@DavidLoeffler $G(\mathbb Q)\backslash G(\mathbb A_f)/K(N)$ is the "descent" I called.

The canonical model of that quotient is a non-geometrically-connected curve over Q whose connected components are defined over Q(zeta_N). So it does not give you a variety over Q whose C-points are Gamma \ H, contrary to your claim.

Or are you happy for the C-points of C(Gamma) to be a disjoint union of multiple copies of Gamma \ H?

Moreover, if X(N) is that quotient viewed as a Q-var, the covering group of X(p q) over X(q) for primes p, q is GL2(Fp), not SL2(Fp) as you seem to want.

Yes, the $\mathbb C$ points of the model is not $H/\Gamma$, and I want exactly disjoint union of  them to be defined over $\mathbb Q$.

@DavidLoeffler The original statement is not strict, I just mean the galois group should like $\Gamma/\Gamma'$ and I have edited the last sentence.

I’m afraid the question is now too vague to be meaningfully answerable.
